# How to map chars to (playing) cards?

Tags: java, android

I have an android card game app. 
In my app i send data about the game cards that has been played between the players, and i try to make the messages as short as possible. 
I have a class that represents each card. 
Now, in order to make the messages smaller, i refer to each card as a single char. 
For example ace of spades would be 'a' 
Ace of diamonds would be 'b' and so on..

My question is, how can i map the chars back to the corresponding card, in the most effective way? 
(For example hashmap of chars and cards) 
For example if a player receives 'a, b' he translates it to aces of spades and diamonds.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not simply use a switch statement?

Comment: I figured a switch with 50+ cases wouldn't be so effective

Comment: What do you mean by 'effectiveness'? Since switch-statements will be translated to jump-marks, it will most likely better perform than HashMaps. In terms of readabilty and maintainability of course, switch-statements might be not the best.

Answer (score 0):

I'd map each card to a character starting with ' ' (32 decimal, 0x20 hex, so you'll always be dealing with printable characters) then just have a switch statement to cover all the cards.  One switch statement to encode, and the other to decode into "Ace of Diamonds" for example.

Although lengthy, a large `switch` statement is better than chained `if-elseif` statements, and easier to understand than a binary encoding.  If I were doing it for a very memory constrained device I might choose binary encoding but for a real computer I'd just use the `switch` as it's easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Switch-case/if-else are ok in this situation. It would get large, but any kind of code where you define 50 mappings would be big.

One other approach would be to "store" your Character<-->Card Relationship somehow and use methods to retrieve the values. You would have the relationships in an easily read manner and it is easy to register mappings and work with it.

I think there is a Map for 1:1 relationships (BiMap from Googles Guava?). You can just register your Characters and Cards in that map so you always can identify in both directions.

If you want to do it without third Party libs, you should be able to easily do it using two maps:

```
/** used to find the correct Card by Character */
private final static Map<Character, Card> mapCharToCard = new HashMap<>();

/** used to find the correct Character by Card (for sending over network) */
private final static Map<Card, Character> mapCardToChar = new HashMap<>();

/* Always stores boths ways so you can always map it back and forth */
public final static void register(Character character, Card card) {

    mapCharToCard.put(character, card);
    mapCardToChar.put(card, character);
}

public final static Character map(Card card) {

    return mapCardToChar.get(card);
}

public final static Card map(Character character) {

    return mapCharToCard.get(character);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    register('a', new Card("Spades", "Ace"));
    register('b', new Card("Heart", "King"));

    System.out.println(map('a'));
    System.out.println(map('b'));

    // Even works with new cards as hashmap uses equals() to check
    System.out.println(map(new Card("Spades", "Ace")));
}

public static class Card {

    private String color;
    private String value;

    public Card(String color, String value) {
        super();
        this.color = color;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Card [getColor()=" + getColor() + ", getValue()=" + getValue() + "]";
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((color == null) ? 0 : color.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((value == null) ? 0 : value.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Card other = (Card) obj;
        if (color == null) {
            if (other.color != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!color.equals(other.color))
            return false;
        if (value == null) {
            if (other.value != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!value.equals(other.value))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```